# Amazon Redshift: Errors after "WHERE DATE = ..."

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, datatable, amazon-redshift, create-table

I am trying to create a temp table in AWS Redshift that takes two dates as a minimum column and a maximum column from a calendar table. This is the code I have:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE DATE_RANGE AS
(
  (SELECT *
  FROM CALENDAR
  WHERE DATE = '2016-12-14') AS MIN_DATE,
  (SELECT *
  FROM CALENDAR
  WHERE DATE = '2022-01-08') AS MAX_DATE
   
)
```

However I keep getting syntax errors after "WHERE DATE =..." and I'm not sure where to go Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: `DATE` is likely a reserved keyword

Comment: Yes, that could be it! Try putting it in quotes, like: `WHERE "DATE" = '2022-01-08'`

Comment: Postgresql doesn't seem to have DATE as reserved (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words). Isn't AWS Redshift having the same set of reserved words?

Comment: I have never seen two queries in the AS part (which you separated by the comma after MIN_DATE), what are you trying to put into the date_range table? If you want all values from both days in the temp table you could use a single query to select them using OR or UNION.

Answer (score 0):

The query, as written, makes no sense: with the parentheses you're trying to turn an entire sub-query into a single column in the `SELECT` list.

If you're trying to select only those rows for the two specific dates, then you can use a query like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE DATE_RANGE AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM CALENDAR
  WHERE "DATE" in ('2016-12-14', '2022-01-08')
)
```

But based on the name of the table, it looks like you actually want to select rows *between* those dates:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE DATE_RANGE AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM CALENDAR
  WHERE "DATE" between '2016-12-14' and '2022-01-08'
)
```

Or maybe, what you really want to do is select the range of dates for data between those two dates:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE DATE_RANGE AS
(
  SELECT min("DATE") as MIN_DATE, max("DATE") as MAX_DATE
  FROM CALENDAR
  WHERE "DATE" between '2016-12-14' and '2022-01-08'
)
```

I suggest that you ask another question, which shows the table that you're selecting from and describes what you want to do with that table.